# Showing that $R$/~ is compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

This is question from general topology.

Question : Let $a$~$b$ iff $a-b$ is an integer. Show that $R$/~ is compact.

But, my attempt : $R$/~ is homoemorphic to $(0, 1]$ . (It’s easily shown)

However, $(0, 1]$ is not closed w.r.t standard metric topology on $R$. Then by heine-borel, it should not be compact...

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You were on the right path. However, the space is not homeomorphic to $(0,1]$ but rather to $[0,1]$ with $0\sim1$, which is homeomorphic to the circle, which is compact.

Comment: If you think "it's easily shown", then show it.

Answer (score 1):

> But, my attempt : $R$/~ is homoemorphic to $(0, 1]$ . (It’s easily shown)

This is were you are wrong: $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is actually not homeomorphic to $(0,1]$.

Consider $S^1=\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ \big|\ \lVert z\rVert=1\big\}$, i.e. the standard sphere and let

$$f:S^1\to \mathbb{R}/\sim$$
$$f(z)=[arg(z)/2\pi]_\sim$$

where $arg$ stands for [the complex argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)). I leave as an exercise that this is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following two continuous maps:
$$i: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$$
the inclusion map $i(x)=x$, and the projection
$$\pi : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R / \sim$$

You can check that the composition $\pi \circ i$ is continuous and surjective.

Thus $\Bbb R / \sim$ is the coninuous image of $[0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, so is $\Bbb R / \sim$.

Note that $\pi (i(0)) = \pi (i (1))$, so this is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: You should mention that $\pi \mid_{(0,1]}$ is a continous bijection, but not a homeomorphism.